# Can we make the "log out" link more discoverable?

Tags: feature-request, design, user-experience, logout

The "log out" link is currently hard to find, as it has historically been (for evidence, see the dozens of previous meta threads asking how to log out).

I suspect part of the current problem is that it is hidden in an illogical place. On the top right corner of the page, there's a list of six (for me) buttons: one with my face on it, and five generic ones. The latter five open menus, but the former does not! It actually takes me to my profile page (where I remain unable to find the "log out" link). This is inconsistency #1.

When I want to log out, I suspect I will find the link under one of those six buttons. Here are quick descriptions of the six:

1. My profile
2. Inbox
3. Reputation
4. Review queues
5. Help
6. Links to other SE sites

Which of those six is the most logical place to put the "log out" link? Under my profile, of course: the button out of the six most likely to be absent when I am not logged in, and the one that is conceptually related to my identity, and thus my presence, on the site. But no, it's under "links to other SE sites". This is inconsistency #2.

Could we move the link somewhere sensible?

Comment: Number 6 is the "community" button. Since you'd be logging out of the entire community, that seems like a reasonable location for the button.

Comment: Unfortunately, the hover text doesn't make that clear. It says, verbatim: "A list of all 174 Stack Exchange sites". I'm not looking for a list of sites.

Comment: ... I never realized those buttons have titles. I usually just click through a site's menu if I can't find something.

Comment: And that's part of my problem: I clicked the first item in a list and it took me to a different page, thereby teaching me that clicking the buttons top right will not open menus.

Comment: Granted, the last icon can be made to look a bit more menu-y. But the way you're describing it makes it sound like the buttons should be fit for training monkeys.

Comment: It probably should be on the toolbar button you use to navigate to the Help pages.

Comment: I think it would make sense to also give the user a way to log out from the profile page. I don't think that whether the icons have menus has to be all or nothing but putting a logout link off the profile would solve it too. (I think it would kind of look weird though.)

Comment: @Henrebotha To help construct a better feature request, when providing evidence, it is much more useful to compile a list of questions proving your point and provide a link to them instead of simply telling readers to "see the dozens of previous meta threads asking how to log out." When a person creates a feature request, the burden of proof that there exists an issue falls on the poster, so instead of telling people to go look for the evidence, you should provide it explicitly.

Comment: They don't want you to unwelcome yourself.

Comment: @DavyM I hear you, I didn't actually think it was necessary here because it's such a common thing I assumed anyone interested in this discussion would already know. Also the "related" sidebar already does that work for me—there's currently three questions in that sidebar specifically asking how to log out, and a few others on log out-related topics.

Comment: @Gimby I'm a software developer, so presumably I'm a bit smarter than a monkey and a bit more at home with computer interfaces than the average human. And I couldn't figure out how to log out. That says a lot more about the design than it does about the user.

Comment: @henrebotha exactly right, you are smarter than the average monkey. So making claims such as "thereby teaching me that clicking the buttons top right will not open menus" is simply ridiculous. You don't need to be taught anything, you will apply sound reasoning skills.

Comment: What about something like this? https://image.ibb.co/dF01kp/2018_08_10_10_52_27_Can_we_make_the_log_out_link_more_discoverable_Meta_Stack_Overflow.png

Comment: @Gimby that flies in the face of all UX knowledge. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_error#Causes Surely you too prefer a system that is easy to use?